# C#-datatable wants to change dynamically in connection string

Tags: c#

I am using an `OLEDB` connection string. I need to iterate automatically for all the datatable available in the loop the code I am using is as follows:

```
Dblist = Directory.GetFiles(foldername,"*.mdb").ToList();
foreach (var db in dblist)
{
     using (var connection=new OleDbConnection("Data Source=c:\\database\\pmgdb\\nd.mdb;Persist Security Info=False;Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"))
     {
     }
}
```

In the above code I just added only one datatable in the connection string I need to dynamically add all the table name in the list to the connection please help.

Comment: Did you paste this code from VS or Word? There's no formatting + the casing that C# will not allow. Please learn some SO (StackOverflow) guidelines before posting.

Comment: I just typed the coding now i edited according to case acceptable in vs

Comment: Please check your spelling and format your code before posting. Here are some guidelines: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. I've done some of the editing but not a language boffin myself :)

Comment: You'll want to search for 'string concatenation', which can be done using the `+` operator or with `string.Concat`. Another option is to use 'string formatting', using `string.Format`.

Answer (score 0):

A connection string can be set to ONE database (.mdb) file  in your case -at a time.

Also, what point in going through the file names you just extracted - if you're going to Hard-code the path to the .mdb file in the connection string ?

What you wanted to do would be something like:

```
List<string> dblist = Directory.GetFiles(foldername,"*.mdb").ToList();
foreach (var db in dblist)
{
     Using (var connection=new OleDbConnection("Data Source=" + db + ";Persist Security Info=False;Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"))
     {
         //my query ...
     }

}
```

What you should be doing, is create a connection array \ list, and assign each connection string to a different connection.

remember to open a connection as late as possible and close a connection as soon as possible.